# What is the right way to make a barrier in distributed tensorflow?

Tags: concurrency, tensorflow

During distributed training I want to sync after each epoch, do some calculations on chief worker and proceed or stop training depending on these calculations. I need a barrier to do so.

I don't see anything similar in documentation, so I implemented solution based on queues (similar to how gradients are stored and applied in distributed training):

```
def build_barrier(tasks, task_index, barrier_name):
    queues = []
    for i, task in enumerate(tasks):
        with tf.device('%s/cpu:0' % task):
            with tf.name_scope(barrier_name):
                queues.append(
                    tf.FIFOQueue(
                        len(tasks),
                        (tf.float32),
                        shapes=(()),
                        name=str(i),
                        shared_name=str(i)))

    with tf.control_dependencies([queue.enqueue(1.) for queue in queues]):
        return queues[task_index].dequeue_many(len(tasks))
```

The idea is to create a queue per worker. For 'signal' I push a token in each queue and for 'join' I dequeue so many tokens from corresponding queue how many tasks I want to synchronize.

The question is: is it the right way to do or there is a better way?

Comment: There's a robust implementation of something like this in SyncReplicas optimizer (ie, works even when some processes die/restart) https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e8e06c5b66d7833ea8715c32c7ab9739714225fc/tensorflow/python/training/sync_replicas_optimizer.py#L34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is quite similar to the [SyncReplicasOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SyncReplicasOptimizer). In SyncReplicasOptimizer, it uses a sync token queue to simulate the barrier, and an accumulator for each variable to accumulate and average the grad update. It's a very typical Bulk Synchronous Parallelism, while it has the additional job of implementing Stale Synchronous Parallelism in Tensorflow.

In addition, Tensorflow provides a [Barrier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/barrier) in the newest version, which you can check for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure tensorflow solution to simulate barriers. Note the use of **two queues** since tensorflow doesn't seem to have a proper solution to atomically increment a variable across distributed sessions, however `queue.size()` thankfully does satisfy this requirement:

```
def tf_barrier(shared_name: str, n_workers: int):
    passing_q = tf.FIFOQueue(n_workers, tf.bool, (), shared_name=shared_name + '_count_q')
    blocking_q = tf.FIFOQueue(n_workers, tf.bool, (), shared_name=shared_name + '_barrier_q')
    increment_size = passing_q.enqueue(True) # Atomically increment queue size
    with tf.control_dependencies([increment_size]):
        incremented_size = passing_q.size()
        return tf.cond(tf.equal(incremented_size, n_workers),
                       lambda: tf.group([blocking_q.enqueue_many([[True] * n_workers]), passing_q.dequeue_many(n_workers)]),
                       lambda: blocking_q.dequeue()
                       )
```

Although internally complicated, it can be used very simply!

```
with create_session(job.name, task_index) as sess: # Assume 6 workers
    start_barrier = tf_barrier('start', 6)
    sess.run(start_barrier)
    # Every 6th run of start_barrier unblocks the 5 runs before it
```